# Is Jetty HttpClient(9.3.8.v20160314) thread-safe and can be used repeatedly?

Tags: multithreading, jetty, jetty-9

Now I create an `org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient` per request.

These requests are stateless and RESTful.

Can I use only one `HttpClient` for all requests which are in parallel, after I invoke its `start()` method?

An `HttpClient` object has lots of fields, can this strategy improve performance and save the memory?